# QGIS Create Feature for closed Polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting, multipart

I have one single layer that consists of different polygons. In the attribute table all the polygons are summarized in one feature (see picture for both).

[image: First]

I am looking for a way to split up the polygons and to create for every closed polygone a new feature (in the next step i want to calculate the area and remove the small dots you can see in the picture to clean it up). Its like the opposite of dissolve.

It should look something like this:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Menu Vector / Geometry tools / Multipart to singleparts`, see the documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts

Your polygons are multipart, thus the feature consists not of one, but of several parts, thus multipart. What you want is to get one part (one geometry) per feature, thus single part.

[image]

Comment: thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for!